# Unable to assign [undefined] to bool для RadioButton

Tags: qtcreator, qml

У меня есть некий Item поверх глав. окна. Задача в нем выбрать режим работы после чего окно закрывается и отображает глав. окно. Я еще не привязывал классы С++ так что большинство похожих вопросов не помогли.
Вылетает ошибка: **Unable to assign [undefined] to bool** во втором случае.

Случай:

1- Создание двух кастомных RadioButton в нужном Item -> Все ОК;

2- Вызов двух кастомных RadioButton в нужном Item из отдельного файла -> ОШИБКА на *visible: parent.checked.*

**DarkRadioButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

RadioButton {

    checked: false

    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 20
        implicitHeight: 20
        x: payloadRole.horizontalPadding
        y: payloadRole.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 0
        border.color: Qt.rgba( 255/255., 0/255., 0/255., 1)
        color: Qt.rgba( 32/255., 32/255., 32/255., 1)

        Rectangle {
            id: radioButtonBox
            width: 16
            height: 16
            x: 2
            y: 2
            Image {
                anchors.fill: radioButtonBox
                source: "qrc:/res/resources/DarkRadioButtonBox.png"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                sourceSize.width: 200
                sourceSize.height: 200
            }
            visible: parent.checked             //!!!!!!!!!! ошибка !!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    }
    contentItem: Text {
        text: parent.text
        font: parent.font
        color: Qt.rgba( 255/255., 255/255., 255/255., 1)
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        leftPadding: parent.indicator.width + parent.spacing
    }
    onCheckedChanged: {
        //some extern value function (not here yet)
        optionsWindow.visible = false
    }
}
```

Место вызова: условно **main.qml**

```
//--- 
Item {
         //---
         ColumnLayout{
                        width:  dialog.width
                        height:  dialog.height
        
                        DarkRadioButton {
                            id: optionA
                            text: qsTr("Option 1")
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                        }
                        DarkRadioButton {
                            id: optionB
                            text: qsTr("Option 2")
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                        }
```

Закрытие Item-а срабатывает, но я планировал и дальше использовать данный шаблон. Не знаю помешает ли эта ошибка так что решил попросить помощи.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать parent и оставить только checked

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, помогло спасибо. ошибок нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в качестве родительского объекта выступает Rectangle, у которого нет свойства checked.

Исправленный вариант

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

RadioButton {
    id: radioButtonRoot_
    checked: false

    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 20
        implicitHeight: 20
        x: payloadRole.horizontalPadding
        y: payloadRole.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 0
        border.color: Qt.rgba( 255/255., 0/255., 0/255., 1)
        color: Qt.rgba( 32/255., 32/255., 32/255., 1)

        Rectangle {
            id: radioButtonBox
            width: 16
            height: 16
            x: 2
            y: 2
            Image {
                anchors.fill: radioButtonBox
                source: "qrc:/res/resources/DarkRadioButtonBox.png"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                sourceSize.width: 200
                sourceSize.height: 200
            }
            visible: radioButtonRoot_.checked
        }
    }
    contentItem: Text {
        text: parent.text
        font: parent.font
        color: Qt.rgba( 255/255., 255/255., 255/255., 1)
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        leftPadding: parent.indicator.width + parent.spacing
    }
    onCheckedChanged: {
        //some extern value function (not here yet)
        optionsWindow.visible = false
    }
}
```